# input of python calculator

Tags: python-3.x, input, calculator

I write project in Python3, which is advanced calculator. It consist of two modules: science calculator and basic calculator. I have a problem with second one. I want to create an input, which doesn't demand spaces between numbers and mathematical symbols. I have no idea, how to do this.
Can you help?

I attached only basic one's part of code, because science module import function from many of my different files.

```
from os import  system
zbior = input().split(" ")
liczby = []
dzialania = []

if zbior[0] == "-" or zbior[0] == "+":
    for i in range(1, len(zbior), 2):
        try:
            zbior[i] = float(zbior[i])
        except ValueError:
            print("Pamiętaj o poprawnym wprowadzeniu działania (odzziel liczby spacją), zobacz instrukcję.")
            # calls the function which loops back code
elif zbior[0]=="m":
    #calls menu function from differnet file
    print("menu")
elif zbior[0] == "+" or str(zbior[0])[0] in "0123456789":
    for i in range(0, len(zbior), 2):
        try:
            zbior[i] = float(zbior[i])
        except ValueError:
            print("Pamiętaj o poprawnym wprowadzeniu działania (odzziel liczby spacją), zobacz instrukcję.")
            # calls the function which loops back code
else:
    print("Pamiętaj o poprawnym wprowadzeniu działania, zobacz instrukcję.")
    # calls the function which loops back code

if zbior[0] == "-" or zbior[0] == "+":
    for znak in zbior:
        if zbior.index(znak) % 2 != 0:
            liczby.append(znak)
        else:
            dzialania.append(znak)
else:
    for znak in zbior:
        if zbior.index(znak) % 2 == 0:
            liczby.append(znak)
        else:
            dzialania.append(znak)

ind = 0
suma = liczby[0]
while (ind+1) <= (len(dzialania)):
    if dzialania[ind] == "+":
        suma += liczby[ind+1]
    if dzialania[ind] == "-":
        suma -= liczby[ind + 1]
    if dzialania[ind] == "*":
        suma = suma*liczby[ind+1]
    if dzialania[ind] == "/":
        if liczby[ind+1] == 0:
            print("""Pamiętaj cholero, nie dziel przez zero!!!""")
            system('cls')
            # calls the function which loops back code
        else:
            suma = suma/liczby[ind + 1]
    if dzialania[ind] == "%":
        if liczby[ind+1] == 0:
            print("""Pamiętaj cholero, nie dziel przez zero!!!""")
            system('cls')
            #calls the function which loops back code
        else:
            suma = suma % liczby[ind + 1]

    ind += 1

print(suma)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not about your calculator, it's about input handling. So please just post where you've got to with code relevant to your non-space-separated input, and identify where you are getting stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what some of the words in your script mean, but if I wanted to input something like `2+2` and get `["2", "+", "2"]` I would do something like this:

```
zbior = [x for x in list(input()) if x != " "]
```

`list(input())` splits every character in the input and `if x != " "` makes sure that whitespaces in the input are ignored.

**Example:**

```
>>> zbior = [x for x in list(input()) if x != " "]
1+2*3+4
>>> zbior
['1', '+', '2', '*', '3', '+', '4']
```

Comment: I mean to get ["2" ,  "+",  "2"] from 2+2 instead of  2 + 2 (to type without space's).

Answer (score 0):

A simple list with skipping spaces then following those characters will work well.

*For now*.

Once you get into more complex expressions you'll have a lot of problems, write a proper mathematical expression evaluator instead. That is, if you really mean *advanced calculator*.

Consider following this guide: https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part1/

By part 6 you'll have a calculator that can evaluate ANY input that has less than a thousand `(` left parentheses before they are closed off by `)`, Python has recursion depth of 1000, it can be increased, but there's a limit for a reason.

What I mean by that, is that it will be fine with an expression that has `"(" * 999` before the first `)` ever occurs, but I wouldn't expect anyone to write such monstrocity unless they are willing to spend next 3 years thinking about an expression or write a mathematical expression generator which is inverse of this. TL;DR - practically, this thing can evaluate anything you'd ever wish for. Advanced calculator for sure.

If you'll like it, you can even continue following it and make your own interpreter, it's slow, and if you want different syntax you'll have to sit for a bit and think about it, but I think it's worth doing at least once in your life.